# Insert into a check table from foreach loop

Tags: php

Am trying to insert variable with foreach loop into a check table and when I run the check.php page I  kepp getting this errors below:

```
Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\database\Check.php on line 18

Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\\myproject\database\Check.php on line 18

Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\\myproject\database\Check.php on line 20

Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\\myproject\database\Check.php on line 20
```

My code to insert is as below.

```
<?php

class Cht{
    public $db = null;

    public function __construct(DBController $db)
    {
        if(!isset($db->con)) return null;
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function insertIntoCh($params = null, $table = "ch") {
        if($this->db->con != null){
            if($params != null){
                
                $columns = implode(',', array_keys($params));

                $values = implode(',', array_values($params));
                
                $query_string = sprintf("INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES (%s)", $table, $columns, $values);
                
                $result = $this->db->con->query($query_string);
                return $result;
            }
        }
    }

    public function addToCh($pid, $kid, $nam, $pc, $qt, $pp){
        if(isset($kid) && isset($pid) && isset($nam) && isset($pc) && isset($qt) && isset($pp)){
            $params = array(
                "p_id" =>$pid,
                "k_id" => $kid,
                "nam" =>$nam,
                "pc" =>$pc,
                "qt" =>$qt,
                "pp" =>$pp
            );

            $result = $this->insertIntoCh($params);
            if($result){
                header("Location:".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me out on this, I can't figure out what I did wrong.
Thanks

The ch.php, the page for insertion

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        if(isset($_POST['chbtn'])){
            $Chkout->addToCh($_POST['pid'],$_POST['kid'],$_POST['nam'],$_POST['pc'],$_POST['qt'],$_POST['pp']);
        }
        
    }

?>

<!--Some html..-->

    <?php
        foreach($prn->getDan('crn') as $itn):
            $crn = $prn->getPrn($itn['p_id']);
            $Total[] = array_map(function($itn){
    ?>

    <!--Some html..-->

        <form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php echo $itn['p_id'] ?? '1'; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="kid" value="<?php echo 1; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="nam" value="<?php echo $itn['nam'] ?? "Unknown"; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="pc"value=" <?php echo $itn['pc'] ?? "0"; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="qt" value="<?php echo $itn['qt'] ?? '0'; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="pp" value="<?php echo $itn['pp'] ?? '0'; ?>">
            <button type="submit" name="chbtn" class="btn btn-warning">add to Checkout</button>&nbsp;
            <br>&nbsp;<br>
        </form>
    <?php
            return $itn['pc'];
            }, $crn);
        endforeach;
    ?>
```

The above code is the page am trying to insert with but when I check the database nothing is inserted

Comment: Is this the only place where you call `insertIntoCh`?

Comment: No, I just figured that out when you pointed it out. I called ```insertIntoCh``` instead of  ```addToCh``` now when I reversed it, no error was thrown but nothing is inserted.

Comment: Well, you're going to have to do some debugging. Check if any of the conditions failed. Print out the query and try to run it directly against the database.

Comment: I had debug as much as I can, still didn't find the problem. included above is my ch.php code.

Comment: Well, what did your debugging efforts show? It's all useful information.

Comment: i couldn't find any error. that was why i pasted ch.php here probably I could be given idea of what to do.

Comment: That's not going to help, because no one other than you can run that code and we don't have access to your values. That's why you need to share the debugging efforts. Don't just say you didn't find anything; show exactly what you've tried and what results you got. Do you have error reporting turned on? Did you check the error log?

Comment: Hi El_Vanja, I tried debugging as suggested, I discovered that if I changed the values in these keys ```"p_id"=>$pid,"k_id"=>$kid, etc``` in the addToCh function to integer, such as ```"p_id =>2,"k_id"=>8,```, etc., it works but the moment its string or variables it doesn't. And those variables are mixtures of integers and strings.
Also, I have to click each item one after another to insert in the CH-table because button is inside foreach loop, that's not what I wanted to achieve. I want a single click of a button to store all items in ch-table, please how do I achieve this too.
Thanks.